Reading and writing large CSV file with custom row terminator in C#
I need to read in various large .csv files of differing schema into SQL Server using SqlBulkCopy class. Initially, I used a DataTable to load the data and convert the data types to the target data types, but this failed due to an OutOfMemoryException. Instead, I want to solve the problem using streaming.
I came up with this working code so far:
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var bulk_data_filename = "myLarge.csv";
        var tablename = "myLargeTable";
        string connectionString = CreateSqlConnectionString("myServer", "myDb");

        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();

            using (var csvFile = new StreamReader(bulk_data_filename))
            {
                using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(csvFile, true, '\t'))
                {
                    
                    var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock | SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepNulls, null);
                    bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;
                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = tablename;
                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(csv);
                }         
            }
        }
    }

    private static string CreateSqlConnectionString(string serverName, string initialCatalog)
    {
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        builder.DataSource = serverName;
        builder.InitialCatalog = initialCatalog;
        builder.IntegratedSecurity = true;
        builder.ApplicationName = "Generic SSIS Import Package";
        return builder.ConnectionString;
    }
}

Unfortunately, I get also interesting .csv files, which contain tab-delimited fields and also tab-delimited rows, which requires me to clean the files before sending to SQL Server.
Now the question: how can I process such files without putting them fully into memory? I tried this code, but still get an OutOfMemoryException:
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var bulk_data_filename = "myLarge.csv";
        var tablename = "myLargeTable";
        string connectionString = CreateSqlConnectionString("myServer", "myDb");

        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();

            using (var csvStream = CleanCsvAndReadIntoMemoryStream(bulk_data_filename))
            {
                using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(csvStream), true, '\t'))
                {
                    var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock | SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepNulls, null);
                    bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;
                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = tablename;
                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(csv);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static string CreateSqlConnectionString(string serverName, string initialCatalog)
    {
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        builder.DataSource = serverName;
        builder.InitialCatalog = initialCatalog;
        builder.IntegratedSecurity = true;
        builder.ApplicationName = "Generic SSIS Import Package";
        return builder.ConnectionString;
    }

    private static MemoryStream CleanCsvAndReadIntoMemoryStream(string filePath)
    {
        //return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(buffer.ToString()));
        using (var outStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(outStream))
            {
                using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(filePath))
                {
                    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
                    string currentLine;

                    while ((currentLine = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        buffer.Append(currentLine);

                        if (buffer.Length > 0 && buffer[buffer.Length - 1] == '\t')
                        {
                            buffer.Remove(buffer.Length - 1, 1);
                            buffer.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                        }

                        streamWriter.Write(buffer.ToString());
                        buffer.Clear();
                        streamWriter.Flush();
                    }

                    if (buffer.Length > 0 && buffer[buffer.Length - 1] == '\n')
                    {
                        buffer.Remove(buffer.Length - 1, 1);
                    }

                    streamWriter.Write(buffer.ToString());
                }

                return outStream;
            }
        }
    }
}

UPDATE: I now enclosed a sample file, that should highlight the structure of the problematic files. I made it intentionally a little bigger such that one can see during debugging if memory goes up or not.
samplefile.csv
When watching the file in notepad++, I can also see, that the actual row delimiter is tab followed by line feed.


Can you give a sample of such a CSV? How do you differentiate between field terminators and rows, if they are both \t? It sounds like you just need to modify the CsvConfiguration.NewLine property

Correctly encoded delimited text files (including CSV) are an implementation of a character-based state machine. Any time you see ReadLine() being used your so-called CSV reader is broken because field data are allowed to contain quotes, delimiter characters and line break characters. Have a read through RFC 4180 Common Format and MIME Type for Comma-Separated Values (CSV) Files for examples.

@Charlieface together with the csv's I get a metadata file, that tells me the number of columns as well as their data type. thus, connecting the dots... :-)
I realized it when I always got one more column than expected

@AlwaysLearning I don't understand the meaning of your comment. You mean, the csv files are malformed? yes, that would be true, but i doubt, that the producer will change them.

Have you asked? Do you think the line-oriented CleanCsvAndReadIntoMemoryStream method actually improves the result?

What @AlwaysLearning is saying is that our CleanCsvAndReadIntoMemoryStream function is fundamentally broken, because it is not taking into account the quoting, so, apart from other issues, in case of embedded newlines you will get malformed data. If you give us an actual sample then we can take a look, it's probably just a matter of configuration of CsvReader.

CSVReader has CsvConfiguration class that allows you to set column delimiters as well as row delimiters. You should not need to write any custom cleaning code. Unless all you get are "simple CSV" i.e. no line breaks or delimiters inside values, writing your own CSV parses is non trivial.

Hey guys, sorry for answering late, but I needed to take care of some other projects last days :-(
the csv delivery will unlikely be changed due to the files being delivered to various destinations. But I will ask the producer, if he can produce a separate export
